# Is there a DNA test to identify dog mixes?

Tags: zoology, dna, dogs

We adopted a dog at the age of two. Our vet said it was a mix of an Australian Shepherd and Border Collie, which we've told everyone. Based on markings, I think it's likely. I am wondering, however, if there are any tests or other ways to know the mix of a dog if you don't know the specific parentage.

Does each dog breed have specific genetic markers that can be used to identify the breed? If so, has a dog breed test been developed or is there no commercial demand for such a test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many commercially available mixed breed ID tests, as a quick Google search will tell you.  However, I cannot vouch for their accuracy: [this news article may be of interest](http://www.mnn.com/family/pets/blogs/dog-breed-tests-do-they-really-work). Also [this](http://news.vin.com/VINNews.aspx?articleId=23206).

The genetic markers used to identify breeds in a mixed-breed are microsatellite markers (sometimes SNPs): you can read more [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/304/5674/1160.abstract), but from the abstract:

> We used molecular markers to study genetic relationships in a diverse collection of 85 domestic dog breeds. Differences among breeds accounted for ∼30% of genetic variation. Microsatellite genotypes were used to correctly assign 99% of individual dogs to breeds.

If you're interested in dog genetics, I encourage you to check out Elaine Ostrander's work.  She's written at least one book for laypeople, in addition to her numerous journal publications.

Comment: I'm not certain of the accuracy of these tests because dog breeds aren't commonly genotyped. I'm not certain if there is a central database of dog breed genotyping, or if there is, whether they have significant sample size to accurately assign a breed.

Comment: @leonardo: The paper managed to separate breeds by genotyping only 5 *unrelated* dogs of each breed, but yes, I agree that the commercial tests are at a disadvantage because of the lack of a common repository (also they might be using SNPs instead of microsatellites) -- this is probably a significant source of the variation between tests.

Comment: Another point that follows from the point made by @leonardo: if in the Parker et al paper, if breeds were separated on the basis of *groups of microsatellites* rather than microsatellites that were unique to each breed, you'd need a lot more markers to identify the heritage of a MBD with any reasonable certainty, so that you'd have clusters of linked markers (the idea being that each cluster was inherited from a single purebred dog).